# Is there a "beforeOutput" type hook in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, hook

I'm building an application with laravel, and when the administration area is accessed, it's supposed to be able to return JSON if it's access via Ajax, or HTML if it's not.

Currently, I have stuff like the below in all my functions. Is there some sort of hook I can use to determine if the request should return JSON or HTML, so I don't have to do it in every method?

```
// if it's accessed via ajax or set the "Accepts:" header to json
        if( Request::ajax() || Request::wantsJson() )
            return Response::json( $inspiration );

        return View::make("admin.inspirations.show")->with("inspiration", $inspiration);
```

Comment: You could add this as a filter to your admin routes.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do it in every method, you can create a flexible method on a Base Controller:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected function makeResult($view, $data, $withs = null)
    {
        if( Request::ajax() || Request::wantsJson() )
            return Response::json( $data );

        $view = View::make("admin.inspirations.show")->with('data', $data);

        if ($withs)
        {
            foreach ($withs as $key => $value)
            {
                $view->with($key, $value);
            }
        }

        return $view;
    }

}
```

And then you you just have, in your controllers, to return:

```
return $this->makeResult("admin.inspirations.show", $inspiration);
```

And if you need to send more data to your view:

```
return $this->makeResult("admin.inspirations.show", $inspiration, ["name" => $user->name]);
```

Comment: It's a shame there is no option to override in controller some method, which handles their call. This solution makes You to rewrite all existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

With laravel you can use [Filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) to hook into routes(before and after). You may need to rethink your "validation" logic, but i think its the best way to go.